Distributed Llama training among multi A100 GPU
I'm currently using the SFT trainer on a Llama 8B model with 16 GB of memory, distributed across 3 A100 GPUs. Initially, I set the parameter per_device_train_batch_size to 8. Given this configuration, I expected to encounter an OutOfMemory issue, as I was interpreting "device" to mean "GPU", but in reality I didn't get any OutOfMemory issue.
However, I recently discovered another parameter in the SFT trainer documentation called per_gpu_train_batch_size. This leads me to believe that "device" does not necessarily equate to "GPU."

Is my understanding correct that "device" and "GPU" are not the same in this context?
Since Hugging Face provides the per_gpu_train_batch_size parameter, does this imply that one might not need to use Accelerate or Distributed Data Parallel (DDP)? Does the SFT trainer handle this automatically?

I set the parameter per_device_train_batch_size > 8, and yet didn't saw any OutOfMemory issue.
But yet I see that my gpu-1 memory is 90% filled up, and gpu-2, 3 are half filled. So gpu are getting used in some way or another.
